# Mysql trigger after insert trigger not working

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I have 3 tables named opproduct, opcategory and opproduct_to_category.The opproduct table has an after insert and an after delete trigger. These triggers modify the category table content column, but it gets the category_id trough opproduct_to_category table. The statments of triggers roughly the same. The after update is working well, but after insert doesn't modify the category table. 
Thanks for your answers!

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS opproduct_AINS;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `opproduct_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `opproduct`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

 DECLARE _category_id INT;

IF new.`status`='1' THEN

    SELECT category_id INTO _category_id 
    FROM opproduct_to_category 
    WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id;

    UPDATE opcategory 
    SET content = content+1 
    WHERE category_id=_category_id;

END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS opproduct_AUPD;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `opproduct_AUPD` AFTER UPDATE ON `opproduct`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE _category_id INT;

 IF NEW.`status`<> OLD.`status` AND NEW.`status`=1 THEN
    SELECT category_id INTO _category_id 
    FROM opproduct_to_category 
    WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id;

    UPDATE opcategory SET content = content+1 
    WHERE category_id=_category_id;

 ELSEIF NEW.`status`<> OLD.`status` AND NEW.`status`=0 THEN

    SELECT category_id INTO _category_id 
    FROM opproduct_to_category 
    WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id;

    UPDATE opcategory SET content = content-1 
    WHERE category_id=_category_id;

 END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```